# How do I get Active Directory Group Name from Sharepoint programmatically?

Tags: permissions, active-directory, spprincipal

So my problem is this:

I have created a Sharepoint Group and added a New User, which in fact is an Active Directory
Group.
Now I loggin using an account from this Active Directory Group.
I need this user active directory group name, in code?
How can I grab it?

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<String> GetADGroups()
{
    List<String> result = new List<String>();

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ServerName, UserName, Password);
    GroupPrincipal findAllGroups = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, "*");
    PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllGroups);
    foreach (Principal group in ps.FindAll())
    {
        result.Add(group.Name);
    }

    return result;
}
```