# Pull SPGroups for a Site and list in a Dropdown using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, permissions

I am struggling with a project that requires me to get the SPGroups(includes AD groups) for a site and populate a dropdown list with the AD groups returned.
Not sure if I am on the right track but any suggestions would be appreciated. This is where I am at on pulling the groups. Getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] for output.

```
            public List<String> GetSiteGroups(string SiteURL)
    {
        List<String> groups = new List<String>();
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPGroupCollection sitegroups =  web.Groups;
                    foreach (SPRoleAssignment assignedRoles in web.RoleAssignments)
                    {
                        if (!(assignedRoles.Member is SPGroup))
                        {
                             ddlList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(assignedRoles.Member.Name.ToString()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         });
        return groups;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. 
I updated the code in my question with my latest version.
I am pulling all the SPGroups, directly added users and domain groups but I only want the domain groups. I was able to exclude the SPGroups but have not been able to remove the directly added users.  
I am trying to figure out how to exclude the directly added users or pull only the domain groups. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the right track as far as SharePoint Groups are concerned. However, for the Active Directory Groups you might want to check this [How do I get Active Directory Group Name from Sharepoint programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59330/how-do-i-get-active-directory-group-name-from-sharepoint-programmatically)